# Angular $watch does not get 'newVal'

Tags: angularjs

I have been trying to show some messages a backend returns with a response for Angular ajax call.
I have a service for sharing data for different controllers (ShareDataService).

```
'use strict';
var angularPOC = angular.module('angularPOC');
  angularPOC.factory('ShareDataService', [ '$timeout', function($timeout) {
  var messages = [];
  var service = {
    setMessage : function(messageText, messageType) {
      $timeout(function() {
        messages = [];
        messages.push({
          'text' : messageText,
          'type' : messageType});
    });
  };
  return service;
}]);
```

Then I have a controller which depends on the data set in service and is supposed to update the view according to data changes:

```
'use strict';
var MessageControllers = angular.module('MessageControllers', []);
var angularPOC = angular.module('angularPOC');
angularPOC.controller('MessageController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$timeout', 'ShareDataService', function($scope, $routeParams, $timeout, ShareDataService) {

  $scope.shareService = ShareDataService;
  $scope.messages = ShareDataService.messages;
  $scope.$watch('ShareDataService.messages',
    function(newVal) {
      alert("newval: " + JSON.stringify(newVal));
      alert("sharedata: " + JSON.stringify(scope.shareService.messages));
      $scope.messages = newVal;
      // or
      // $scope.getMessages();
    }
  );

  $scope.getMessages = function() {
    $scope.messages = ShareDataService.getMessages();
    return $scope.messages;
  };
}]);
```

The $watch will catch "some" event that the underlying data changes, but the 'alert' will show that the 'newVal' is 'undefined'.
The 'sharedata' will print the messages as they were before before they were changed.
Also when trying to use the method to explicitly get the data, it will fererence to the old data.

However if I put a button on the page to explicitly call the getMessages() from the scope, it will get the correct data!

It kind of seems that the "service" is one step behind from what it should be in the $watch.

I have read couple of examples/tutorials on how to use the $watch and this seems correct to me, however it does not work as supposed to?

Please advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know the reason behind this, I had a similar issue some months back and got it resolved by doing as below

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return ShareDataService.getMessages() }, function (){
    //your code
});
```

Not sure if this is the right solution. Use it if nothing else works out for you.

Comment: Wow. You just gave me that warm fuzzy feeling which you get when you try to get something to work for a long time and finally succeed. :D It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$watch` isn't working is because you don't have a property called `ShareDataService` on the `$scope`.

You've named the property `shareService`, so the correct `$watch` invocation is:

```
$scope.shareService = ShareDataService;
$scope.$watch('shareService.messages', function(newVal) {
    $scope.messages = newVal;
});
```

**Edit:**
And as doodeec correctly pointed out you are missing the `messages` property on the `ShareDataService` as well:

```
var angularPOC = angular.module('angularPOC');
angularPOC.factory('ShareDataService', ['$timeout',
    function($timeout) {
        var messages = [];
        var service = {
            setMessage: function(messageText, messageType) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    messages = [];
                    messages.push({
                        'text': messageText,
                        'type': messageType
                    });
                });
            },
            messages: messages
        };
        return service;
    }
]);
```